# Airbags deployed for hitting a side mirror

Tags: toyota, supplemental-restraint-system, 4runner, accident, mirrors

A friend hit the side mirror to a pole and airbags on both driver and passenger side deployed. Any ides why?

Toyota 4Runner 2017

[image]

Comment: "*A friend hit the side mirror to a pole, Any ideas why?*"  Because A friend hit the side mirror to a pole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a side collision senor in the mirror. May also be close by in the door.

Now, buy new airbags and be **very** careful fitting them.

Good luck getting “friend” to pay...

Comment: I thought the sensors were only in the door! Mirror sensor created unnecessary action haha. Thanks!

Comment: In an accident the wing mirrors are going to be the first thing to be hit, giving the most time for the air bag to deploy before impact.